# @JsonManagedReference возвращает пустой объект

Tags: spring, hibernate, many-to-many

Есть две таблицы многие-ко-многим `Domain, View`, и связывающая их таблица `Permissions`, при попытке вытащить запись из Domains - получаю пустые Permissions, (без @JsonManagedReference @JsonBAckreference- `Permissions` не пустые, но превращаются в бесконечную рекурсию)
Как правильно организовать данные модели?

UPD: число объектов Permissions правильное, то есть из базы он вытаскивает что-то, но они пустые, как будто не хватает гетеров-сеттеров
 Domain:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "domain")
public class Domain {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private String reference;

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }


  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }


  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getReference() {
    return reference;
  }

  public Set<ViewDomainPermissions> getPermissions() {
    return permissions;
  }


  public void setPermissions(Set<ViewDomainPermissions> permissions) {
    this.permissions = permissions;
  }


  public void setReference(String reference) {
    this.reference = reference;
  }

  @OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "domain",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    orphanRemoval = true
  )
  @JsonManagedReference
  private Set<ViewDomainPermissions> permissions =
    new HashSet<>();

}
```

View:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "view")
public class View {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private String description;

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }


  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }


  public void setDescription(String reference) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  @OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "view",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    orphanRemoval = true
  )
  @JsonManagedReference
  private Set<ViewDomainPermissions> permissions =
    new HashSet<>();
}
```

Permissions:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "view_domain_permissions")

public class ViewDomainPermissions {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @JsonBackReference
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
             optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "domain", nullable = false)
  private Domain domain;

  public Domain getDomain() {
    return domain;
  }

  public void setDomain(Domain domain) {
    this.domain = domain;
  }

  @JsonBackReference
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
             optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "view", nullable = false)
  private View view;

  public View getView() {
    return view;
  }

  public void setView(View view) {
    this.view = view;
  }


}
```

Огромное спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите `= new HashSet<>()`.
Чтоб не было бесконечной рекурсии используйте аннотацию @JsonIgnore, в том объекте где не хотите подтягивать связи.

Например так:

Domain

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "domain")
  public class Domain {

     @Id
     private Long id;

     private String name;

     private String reference;



     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "domain", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
     private Set<ViewDomainPermissions> permissions;


  //getters and setters 


  }
```

View

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "view")
  public class View {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private String description;

  @JsonIgnore
  @OneToMany( mappedBy = "view", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true )
  private Set<ViewDomainPermissions> permissions;


  //getters and setters 


  }
```

Permissions:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "view_domain_permissions")
  public class ViewDomainPermissions {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;


  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "domain_id", nullable = false)
  private Domain domain;


  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "view_id", nullable = false)
  private View view;


  //getters and setters  


  }
```

Comment: Попробовала как вы описали - стал ругаться на Empty_Bean, добавила @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler", "domain", "view"})
- все осталось как было, view -  пустые

Comment: Добавил в ответ пример

Comment: Ваш пример работает, но в нем при вытаскивании домена в нем отсутствует поле  permissions вообще, а если @JsonIgnore поставить в класс Permissions поле Domain - то получается как в первом моем комментарии

Comment: Что поле отсутствует это нормально, там для этого и стоит @JsonIgnore, на сколько я понял если вы просто поднимаете домен, то это поле вам не нужно, оно имеет значение только в связке с view. Если у вас будет view то по ней вы сможете определить permissions. Или можно наоборот во view поставить `JsonIgnore`

Comment: задача вытащить домен и в нем иметь соответствующие ему permissions в которых я посмотрю разрешенные для это домена view. Я вопрос апдейтнула - permissions вытаскиваются в верном количестве, но пустые

Comment: Переместите тогда во view  аннотацию @JsonIgnore над permitions. Эта аннотация нужна только для разрыва циклической зависимости в json

Comment: Переместила во view - получается бесконечная рекурсия в ответе,  в домене - permissions, в которых домен и так далее

Comment: Странно. У вас код на github? Можно посмотреть?

Comment: Получилось, добавила @JsonIgnore в два места: и во  View  и в Permissions к полю Domain - и так сработало, спасибо огромное